# MySQL: Subqueries in the FROM Clause

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
Select cat.Title,cat.CategoryId,count(*) as Count 
from Companies,
     (Select MallCategories.CategoryId, MallCategories.Title 
      from MallCategories  
      JOIN Malls ON MallCategories.MallId = Malls.MallId 
      WHERE Malls.MallId='5410708140ab88a90f7b23c7') AS cat 
WHERE Companies.MallCategory=cat.CategoryId
GROUP BY cat.CategoryId
```

This query works fine on `sqlite`  database, But when I use it on `mysql` it returns this error

```
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 67)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 67)
SQL query: Documentation

Select cat.Title,cat.CategoryId,count(*) as Count from Companies, ( LIMIT 0, 25

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2
```

Where I am doing wrong?Can you please help me with it?thanks

---

Ps:well this is what I have done and it works now,
I changed it into this form

```
Select cat.Title,cat.CategoryId,count(*) as Count 
  from 
  (Select MallCategories.CategoryId, MallCategories.Title 
  from MallCategories JOIN Malls ON MallCategories.MallId = Malls.MallId       
  WHERE  Malls.MallId='5410708140ab88a90f7b23c7') AS cat, 
  Companies 
WHERE Companies.MallCategory=cat.CategoryId 
GROUP BY cat.CategoryId
```

And it worked, I have no idea what happened here

Comment: extra parenthesis.

Comment: I think a `select` in `from` does not work in mysql

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen where?I checked and there is only a () around second select statment

Comment: @rbr94 indeed it must work..based on this documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html

Comment: Are you trying to execute this query in phpmyadmin? Because it seem to me that phpmyadmin is injecting its own usual `limit` clause into the query - just at the wrong place. Try to execute the query from a different MySQL client.

Comment: @rb94 MySQL has been supporting subqueries in the from clause for well over a decade.

Comment: @Shadow yes I am executing it from phpmyadmin,But When I run it form a php file it give me error,It seems there is sth wrong with query itself.The database is set up correctly and other queries works fine

Comment: What's the error you get if you execute the sql statement from php code yourself?

Comment: @Shadow In fact it returns an empty json result.

Comment: @Shadow I have updated my question, Can you guess why it is corrected now?

Comment: What have you changed? Did you just turn it into a single line?

Comment: @Shadow no,In fact I changed the name of tables in from cluse, It was 'from Companies, (Select ...) as cat' and I changed it into 'from (Select ...) as cat,Companies'

Comment: No, that should not have any effect on the syntax. I think you bumped into a phpmyadmin bug and then you had some other formatting issue in the php code.